# How to change value for rows that meet specific conditions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I want to change the name in the name column to `default` for only rows that meet a specific condition (`name == None` and `weight == 1`). As you can see weight can be 10, but I do not want to change the names for weights of 10. Here is a small example dataframe:

```
post   name  weight  response
blah1  None       1       yes
blah2  None      10        no
blah3  Annie      1       yes
```

How can I achieve this in a simple way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a fast, solid, robust Panda-esque solution:

```
df.loc[(df.name == None) & (df.weight == 1), 'name'] = 'defaut'
```

Comment: This is a solid answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can `update` the dataframe with a filled in version of the `'name'` column.

```
df.update(df.name[df.weight.eq(1)].fillna('default'))

df

    post     name  weight response
0  blah1  default       1      yes
1  blah2     None      10       no
2  blah3    Annie       1      yes
```

Answer (score 2):

```
np.where((df['name'] == 'None') & (df['weight'] == 1), 'default', df['name'])
```